# Removing duplicates and keeping one copy

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I have been going through the threads about removing duplicates from a table and keeping one copy .I have seen an illustration in the case one have a table with composite key.anyone with the idea ?

table contr with composite key checkno,salary_month,sal_year

```
delete (select * from CONTR t1
    INNER JOIN
 (select CHECKNO, SALARY_YEAR,SALARY_MONTH FROM CONTR 
group by CHECKNO, SALARY_YEAR,SALARY_MONTH HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dupes 
ON 
t1.CHECKNO = dupes.CHECKNO AND
t1.SALARY_YEAR= dupes.SALARY_YEAR AND
t1.SALARY_MONTH=dupes.SALARY_MONTH);
```

I expected one duplicate to be removed and one maintained.

Comment: What is the logic by which one of the duplicates gets spared?

Comment: Has this SQL work for you? Did you get an error message? What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this assuming you have dupes with 3 columns you have mentioned is

1. Create a temp table with distinct values
2. Drop your table
3. Rename the temp table

Especially if you are dealing huge volume of data this way would be a lot faster than delete.

If the dup data you are working on is subset of your main table the steps would be

1. Create a temp table with distinct values
2. Delete all dup columns from main table
3. Insert data from temp table to main table

The SQL for the first step would be

```
create table tmp_CONTR AS 
select distinct CHECKNO, SALARY_YEAR,SALARY_MONTH   -- this part can be modified to match your needs 
  from CONTR t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query below to remove duplicates by using `rowid` as having a unique valued column :

```
delete contr t1
 where rowid <
     (
      select max(rowid)
        from contr t2
       where t2.checkno = t1.checkno
         and t2.salary_year = t1.salary_year
         and t2.salary_month = t1.salary_month
      );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8c237da45bd9acc5b550f35286340fda)</kbd>

Comment: Thanx.This works fine if a want to remove duplicates and maintain one copy.I have another case where i now want to remove duplicates and keep a copy for a specific number.I modied the script to